# VBScript - Assign source code of web page to variable

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBScript that looks navigates a website based on the content of that website. To do that, I need to be able to assign the source code of each web page to a string variable and have the script look through that string for certain words.

I have seen this proposed as a solution:

```
Function GetSourceCode(url)
     Set objHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
     bGetAsAsync = False

     objHttp.open "GET", url, bGetAsAsync
     objHttp.send

     If objHttp.status <> 200 Then
         wscript.Echo "unexpected status = " & objHttp.status & vbCrLf & objHttp.statusText
         wscript.Quit
     End If

     'MsgBox objHttp.responseText

     GetSourceCode = objHttp.responseText
End Function
```

but that does not work. I've seen elsewhere that this is possible with AutoIT, but I cannot use AutoIT per security policy.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/290761/frequently-asked-questions-about-serverxmlhttp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` to `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP`

```
Function GetSourceCode(url)
     Set objHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
     bGetAsAsync = False

     objHttp.open "GET", url, bGetAsAsync
     objHttp.send

     If objHttp.status <> 200 Then
         wscript.Echo "unexpected status = " & objHttp.status & vbCrLf & objHttp.statusText
         wscript.Quit
     End If

     'MsgBox objHttp.responseText

     GetSourceCode = objHttp.responseText
End Function

WScript.Echo GetSourceCode("https://anothervps.com/api/phpver")
```

[image]